# What is this character in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Pulling in info from a web scrape, I got this name:

```
>> temp
"Rob Bolden"
>>temp.split " " #space bar
["Rob Bolden"]
>>temp.split /\s/
["Rob Bolden"]
>>temp.split /\s+/
["Rob Bolden"]
>>temp.split /\W/
["Rob", "Bolden"] #what I expected
```

What is not a space character (`/\s/`) but is a non-word character (`/\W/`)?

**EDIT**

```
$ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

Comment: What is the unicode encoding of the web page and what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: @twmb - How can I find out the encoding?

Comment: If you're not dealing with simple ASCII, you should be using `\p{Space}`, `\p{Word}`, `\p{^Word}`, ... instead of `\s`, `\w`, `\W`, ...

Comment: Unicode character properties.

Comment: @echristopherson - can you point me toward some documentation? I can't seem to google the right term

Comment: I was going to suggest googling `"unicode character properties"`, but actually I'm not finding much that way. There's a table of them in *Programming Ruby 1.9*, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Ruby 1.9.2, you could use [`ord`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ord) as in:

```
"Rob Bolden"[3].ord
```

Comment: `>> temp[3].ord` is `160` (non breaking space)

Answer (score 4):

It’s probably U+00A0 (non-breaking space).

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = "Rob" << 160.chr << "Bolden"
```

Which is:

```
ASCII  ASCII          HTML    HTML   
Dec    Hex    Symbol  Number  Name    Description 
--------------------------------------------------------
160    A0             &#160;  &nbsp;  non-breaking space
```